# variable in XML subelement

Tags: python, xml, tree, elementtree

I'm thinking of Python code to create a dynamic xml ETREE subElement.

I have a hierarchical header to describe a peace of book as the following:

```
<Books>
<Booktype List= "Story > Fiction > Young">
#here the rest of book text
</Booktype>
<Booktype List= "Science > Math > Young">
#here the rest of book text
</Booktype>
</Books>
```

How to get a hierarchical xml tag like this :

```
<Books>
<Booktype>
  <Story>
    <Fiction>
         <Young>
#here the rest of book text
         </Young>
    </Fiction>
  </Story>
</Booktype>
</Books>
```

This is my code:

```
import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree import ElementTree


List= "Story>Fiction>Young"
List = List.split('>')
root = ET.Element('Books')
Booktype =ET.SubElement(root,'Booktype')

for l in List:
  ND = ET.SubElement(Booktype,str(l))
  Booktype.append(ND)

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
ElementTree.tostring(root,'utf-8')
```

I got this bad result:

```
'<Books><Booktype><Story /><Story /><Story /><Fiction /><Fiction /><Young /><Young /><Story /><Story /><Fiction /><Fiction /><Young /><Young /></Booktype></Books>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to nest the list elements you have to keep the reference to the previous one so you can add the child element to it, and not to the `Booktype` element. See the variable `currrent` in the examples.

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

xml_string = '''<Books>
<Booktype List= "Story > Fiction > Young">
#here the rest of book text
</Booktype>
<Booktype List= "Science > Math > Young">
#here the rest of book text 2
</Booktype>
</Books>
'''

xml = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
for booktype in xml.findall('Booktype'):
    types = map(lambda x: x.strip(), booktype.get('List').split('>'))
    current = booktype
    for t in types:
        current = ET.SubElement(current, t)
    current.text = booktype.text
    booktype.text = ''
    del booktype.attrib['List']
print ET.tostring(xml,'utf-8')
```

Gives me the result:

```
<Books>
<Booktype><Story><Fiction><Young>
#here the rest of book text
</Young></Fiction></Story></Booktype>
<Booktype><Science><Math><Young>
#here the rest of book text 2
</Young></Math></Science></Booktype>
</Books>
```

And if you want to create a completely new structure you can do:

```py
xml = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
root = ET.Element('Books')
for booktype in xml.findall('Booktype'):
    current = ET.SubElement(root, 'Booktype')
    for t in map(lambda x: x.strip(), booktype.get('List').split('>')):
        current = ET.SubElement(current, t)
    current.text = booktype.text
print ET.tostring(root, 'utf-8')
```